# Get Selected Items from a GridView

Tags: gridview, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I have a GridView like this:

```
<GridView x:Name="MyGrid" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Wallpapers}" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:ImageItem">
            <Image Width="150" Height="150" Source="{x:Bind img}" Tag="{x:Bind TagIndex}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

I need to get selected Image controls to obtain their Tag property.
I tried like this:

```
foreach (Image img in MyGrid.SelectedItems)
{
    int index = img.Tag as int;
}
```

But I get System.InvalidCastException. How can I do that?

Comment: What does your debugger tell you about the type of the `Tag` property at runtime?

Comment: It gives me System.InvalidCastException on foreach line. The tag property is set correctly as int

Comment: Executing the code might give you that, but using the debugger should tell you *why*. I'd always recommend breaking on all CLR exceptions when thrown

Comment: No debug stops while it try to cast MyGrid.SelectedItems to Image. It only tell me that SelectedItems is System._ComObject type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive an InvalidCast exception because the members of the gridview SelectedItems collection are of the same type as the items in the collection to which the gridview ItemsSource property is bound (ImageItem in the given example).

Therefore, the following code could be used to get the tag index directly:

```
foreach (ImageItem imgItem in MyGrid.SelectedItems)
{
    int index = imgItem.TagIndex;
}
```

Or using the var keyword:

```
foreach (var imgItem in MyGrid.SelectedItems)
{
    var index = imgItem.TagIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Removed old answer.

Try something like this

```
foreach(var item in MyGrid.SelectedItems)
{
    var image = item as TheTypeInItemsSource;//This is the type you have used in ItemsSource
    int index = image.TagIndex;
}
```

I don't have Win10 on this pc to test it right now so I'm not sure it works.

The SelectedItems of a GridView are of the same type as the ones in ItemsSource. From my understanding the type of the items you provided as a source to the GridView contain an image and an integer which is the TagIndex. Just get the TagIndex of the item instead of the Tag from the Image control.